# C# Extract data from complex XML

Tags: c#, xml

I have the following XML where I am trying to extract a field.

```
<env:Envelope xmlns:env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <env:Header xmlns:work="http://bea.com/2004/06/soap/workarea/">
      <work:WorkContext xmlns:wsu="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2002/07/utility">
         <java class="java.beans.XMLDecoder">
            <string>weblogic.app.MerchantQueryWebService</string>
            <int>214</int>
            <string>weblogic.workarea.StringWorkContext</string>
            <string>2.0</string>
            <string/>
         </java>
      </work:WorkContext>
   </env:Header>
   <env:Body>
      <m:RequestTransactionByTimeIntervalDetailedResponse xmlns:m="http://www.zain.com/">
         <m:RequestTransactionByTimeIntervalDetailedResult>
            <java:Status xmlns:java="java:com.obopay.ws.merchantquery.zain">0</java:Status>
            <java:TotalTransactions xmlns:java="java:com.obopay.ws.merchantquery.zain">3</java:TotalTransactions>
            <java:TotalAmount xmlns:java="java:com.obopay.ws.merchantquery.zain">13</java:TotalAmount>
            <java:Transactions xmlns:java="java:com.obopay.ws.merchantquery.zain">[4736510#254780852341#2#0#55#2018-01-18 11:05:14.166#Name]</java:Transactions>
            <java:Message xmlns:java="java:com.obopay.ws.merchantquery.zain">Success</java:Message>
         </m:RequestTransactionByTimeIntervalDetailedResult>
      </m:RequestTransactionByTimeIntervalDetailedResponse>
   </env:Body>
</env:Envelope>
```

I wish to get the the data from  node but I am facing a difficulty.

Below is my code:

```
XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
xmlDoc.LoadXml(ServiceResult);
string xpath ="m:RequestTransactionByTimeIntervalDetailedResponse/m:RequestTransactionByTimeIntervalDetailedResult/";
var nodes = xmlDoc.SelectNodes(xpath);
foreach (XmlNode childrenNode in nodes)
{
   HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(childrenNode.SelectSingleNode("//java:Transactions").Value);  
}
```

Comment: Two things: a) you need an `XmlNamespaceManager` with your `.SelectNodes` . b) Where in the XML is the definition for the `java:` prefix? You need that in order to properly prepare your `XmlNamespaceManager` and then to compile the correct XPath with the correct prefixes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on guidance by Tom W, i used the following code and worked perfectly:

```
using (StreamReader rd = new StreamReader(Serviceres.GetResponseStream()))
                {
                    //reading stream  
                    var ServiceResult = rd.ReadToEnd();
                    XmlDocument xDoc = new XmlDocument();
                    xDoc.LoadXml(ServiceResult);
                    XmlNamespaceManager xmlnsManager = new XmlNamespaceManager(xDoc.NameTable);
                    xmlnsManager.AddNamespace("env", "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/");
                    xmlnsManager.AddNamespace("work", "http://bea.com/2004/06/soap/workarea/");
                    xmlnsManager.AddNamespace("m", "http://www.zain.com/");
                    xmlnsManager.AddNamespace("java", "java:com.obopay.ws.merchantquery.zain");
                    string transactions = xDoc.SelectSingleNode("env:Envelope/env:Body/m:RequestTransactionByTimeIntervalDetailedResponse/m:RequestTransactionByTimeIntervalDetailedResult/java:Transactions", xmlnsManager).ChildNodes[0].InnerText;
                }
```

Answer (score 1):

Your xpath is wrong - SelectNodes statements are scoped from the node that the xpath is executed against, which in your case is the document element. Provide the whole path to the desired nodes.

Furthermore, you haven't defined what namespace your `m:` namespace prefix refers to - create an `XmlNamespaceManager`, call `AddNamespace` on it to provide each relevant namespace, and pass it as an argument to `SelectNodes`.

Comment: Thanks Tom W. I followed your directions and it worked fine.